# JavaScript fetch() Discord file upload results in a HTTP 400 "cannot send empty message, 50006" error

Tags: javascript, file, upload, discord, fetch-api

I am trying to upload a single PNG file to a Discord channel using a webhook using vanilla javascript because I cannot use Discord.js.

In Chrome's JavaScript console, I get the following error message:

> POST https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/<my discord webhook> 400

Followed by this `console.log()` output:

> Success: {message: "Cannot send an empty message", code: 50006}

I include my code and the Network console transcript at the end, but I have 1 question:

- what am I doing wrong? I see that `Content-Disposition` for the file is of type `form-data`, any connection to my problem?

Before that, I managed to post messages (json only, no files) using both XMLHttpRequest and fetch.

I did not try using JQuery although I could and would prefer a pure Javascript solution.

Below is the code I wrote, to send a single PNG image as well as a payload_json JSON data payload (same error without the payload):

```js
    const filename = 'image.png';
    domtoimage.toBlob(document.querySelector('<element to snapshot selector>'))
      .then(function (blob) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        var params = {
          username: "My bot name",
          avatar_url: "",
          content: "another test 2",
          embeds: [{
            "image": {
              "url": "https://i.imgur.com/ZGPxFN2.jpg"
            }
          }]
        };
        formData.append('payload_json',JSON.stringify(params))
        formData.append('file',blob);
        fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/<my discord webhook>', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
          body: formData,
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
          console.log('Success:', result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        });
      });
```

In Chrome's Network console, I get the following information:

```
General
    Request URL: https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/<my discord webhook>
    Request Method: POST
    Status Code: 400 
    Remote Address: 162.159.134.233:443
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
    access-control-allow-credentials: true
    access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Track, X-Super-Properties, X-Context-Properties, X-Failed-Requests, X-Fingerprint, X-RPC-Proxy, X-Debug-Options, x-client-trace-id, If-None-Match, X-RateLimit-Precision
    access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
    access-control-allow-origin: <access-control-allow-origin>
    access-control-expose-headers: Retry-After, X-RateLimit-Global, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-RateLimit-Bucket, Date
    cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
    cf-ray: <cf-ray>
    cf-request-id: <cf-request-id>
    content-length: 58
    content-type: application/json
    date: Thu, 16 Jul 2020 04:23:41 GMT
    expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
    server: cloudflare
    set-cookie: __cfduid=<__cfduid>; expires=Sat, 15-Aug-20 04:23:40 GMT; path=/; domain=.discordapp.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
    set-cookie: __cfruid=<__cfduid>; path=/; domain=.discordapp.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
    status: 400
    strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
    via: 1.1 google
    x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 27
    x-ratelimit-bucket: <x-ratelimit-bucket>
    x-ratelimit-limit: 5
    x-ratelimit-remaining: 4
    x-ratelimit-reset: <x-ratelimit-reset>
    x-ratelimit-reset-after: 2
Request Headers
    :authority: discordapp.com
    :method: POST
    :path: /api/webhooks/<my discord webhook>
    :scheme: https
    accept: */*
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: en,en-US;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8
    content-length: 50696
    content-type: multipart/form-data
    origin: https://<origin>
    referer: https://<referer>
    sec-fetch-dest: empty
    sec-fetch-mode: cors
    sec-fetch-site: cross-site
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
    ------WebKitFormBoundarypu7GvABzASKKKTQF
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="payload_json"

    {"username":"WhiteBoard","avatar_url":"https://i.imgur.com/ZGPxFN2.jpg","content":"another test 2","embeds":[{"image":{"url":"https://i.imgur.com/ZGPxFN2.jpg"}}]}
    ------WebKitFormBoundarypu7GvABzASKKKTQF
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob"
    Content-Type: image/png

    ‰PNG
    

    IHDRpíã IDAT[...]
    [...]:cjIEND®B`‚
    ------WebKitFormBoundarypu7GvABzASKKKTQF--
```

**-------- Edit (2020/07/16 14:30): Answering my secondary question myself --------**

- why is the filename part in the request payload "blob"?
  `FormData.append()` accepts a third parameter with the filename, my code should look like below:

```
    formData.append('file',blob,filename);
```

Comment: Any update from this? I am experiencing the same problem

Comment: Sorry, I got no answer, it seems you'll have to find a way to store your image files somewhere else, or reverse engineer what Discord.js does to get the job done ... In my case we just abandoned hooking with Discord for now and moreover, we might be able to use Discord.js in the future ... Anyway a vanilla js answer would be welcome.

Answer (score 4):

A build a simple js functions to resize images on client site side before sent to server.
I get the result in base64 encoded and make a blob with this function

```js
const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) => {
  const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  const byteArrays = [];
  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }

  const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  return blob;
}
```

Then, I send a image as blob to discord webhook with fetch

```js
function sendMessage(img, obj=false) {
  console.log("send")
  const WH_URL = "YOUR_URL"
  if(!obj)
    obj = {
      content: ''
    }
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("file", img, "img.png");
  formdata.append("payload_json", JSON.stringify(obj));
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: formdata,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };
fetch(WH_URL, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

### Full Example:

```js
const resizeImage = data =>{
  return new Promise( r =>{
    let dst, ctx, width, start, time, _data;
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = data
    img.onload = () => {
      width = 300;
      dst = document.createElement("canvas")
      ctx = dst.getContext("2d")
      dst.width = width;
      dst.height = img.height * width / img.width
      start = performance.now()
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, dst.width, dst.height)
      time = (performance.now() - start).toFixed(2)
      _data = dst.toDataURL()
      r(_data)
    }
  })
}
const readImg = async form =>{
  var files = form.files;
  if (files.length === 0)
    return;
  let data = await resizeImage(window.URL.createObjectURL(files[0]))
  document.querySelector('#img').src = data;
  let b64 = data.split(",")[1] // get only base64
  sendMessage(b64toBlob(b64), { content: 'Resized Image'})
}


function sendMessage(img, obj=false) {
  console.log("send")
  const WH_URL = "YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL"
  if(!obj)
    obj = {
      content: ''
    }
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("file", img, "img.png");
  formdata.append("payload_json", JSON.stringify(obj));
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: formdata,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };
fetch(WH_URL, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}

const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) => {
  const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  const byteArrays = [];
  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }

  const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  return blob;
}
```

```html
<img id="img"/>
<p>
  <input type="file" onchange="readImg(this)"/>
</p>
```

Comment: I think you need to elaborate more on what problem encounter. I run your code snippet and it works.

Comment: I'm not fluent in English, I'm really sorry if it was poorly explained

Comment: It is me who must apologize, I mistook your answer for a question (which of course is lacking - it is an answer :)). I am new to reviewing..

Comment: hehehe and I'm new with responses